# Improve CONCAT, COALESCE, SUBSTRING in the databricks

Tags: sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I am working on making id key using addresses, but it works in the small amount, but when I run it for about 45m rows to write the table, it fails every time I try it. Does any one know how I could improve this query?

```
    LOWER(
      CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING(
          CONCAT(
            REPLACE(COALESCE(tbsemn.Address_1,''), ' ',''),
            REPLACE(COALESCE(tbsemn.Address_2,''), ' ','')
          )
          ,1,10
        ),
        REPLACE(COALESCE(tbsemn.Postcode,''),' ','')
      )
    )
    AS AddressIdKey
```

Comment: How/why does it fail? What error message(s) are you seeing?

Comment: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 7 in stage 324.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 7.4 in stage 324.0 (TID 3934, 10.10.64.15, executor 18): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 18 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages. In my experience it's memory issue @NickW

Comment: If you run the same query but replace the part you've shown with a fixed value does it still error? i.e. are you sure it this part of the query that is causing the issue and not just the fact that you are trying to write 45m records?

Comment: I tried it without it and it worked.

Comment: OK - there doesn't seem to be anything intrinsically wrong with your query so if you are running out of memory, and you can't increase the memory, then the only solution I can think of would be to break this up into separate steps and either write the values back to your source table or to a temporary table. Whether you would need to write each part of the statement out to a new column or combine several parts of the statement would, I guess, depend on how much memory you have and so would be a bit trial-and-error